# Making label tag center

Tags: php, html, css, forms, label

I'm trying to align my label tag's to center under the text but it won't budge. What should I change?
I honestly have no idea why text-align center is not working. I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find anything that works for me personally. Any help is welcome, thank you in regard. - Sjoerd
Code: {html}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Guardian - a safe online storage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <header>
            <div class="container flex">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>Guardian</h1>
                    <p>A service to store your information</p>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <a class="active" href="index.html"> Home </a>
                    <a href="forms.html"> All your information </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="banner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="main-text">

                    </div>
                    <img src="img/guardian-logo.jpg" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <h2> This is where you will store your information:</h2>
                    <div class="data">
                        <form action="forms_script/formsHandler.php" method="POST">
                            <label for="name">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fullName" placeholder="Enter full name" name="fullName">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" id="pswd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
                            <label>
                            </label>
                            <button type="submit">Opslaan</button>
                        </form>

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>

        <footer>

        </footer>

    </body>

</html>



**CSS Part**

    body{
        font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }


    .title p {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .title h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    nav a {
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav .active {
        background-color: #76C38F;
        border-radius: 10px;

    }

    header {
        border-top: 3px solid #F2A102;
        border-right: 3px solid #F2A102;
        border-left: 3px solid #F2A102;
        background-color: #815B40; 
        color: white; 
    }

    /* ==========================================================================
                                    main
    ========================================================================== */

    .banner {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #F2A102;
        border-right: 3px solid #F2A102;
        border-left: 3px solid #F2A102;
        background-color: #F68026;
        color: white;
    }

    .banner h2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .data {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 150%;
        font-size: .85em;
    }

    .data input {
        display: block;
    }
    /* ==========================================================================
    Helper classes
    ========================================================================== */

    .container {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }



{php}

<h1>PHP test website</h1>

<?php

    $errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    $name = $_POST['fullName'];
    $pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    echo "$pswd &nbsp;";
     // str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5); // adds 5 spaces   
    echo "$email &nbsp";

    echo "$name";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) 
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorMessage');</script>";
    }



     file_put_contents("../dpkfnkshjdbfjsdbfjsd/email_list.txt", "$email", FILE_APPEND); // put in data 

      file_put_contents("../dpkfnkshjdbfjsdbfjsd/password_list.txt", "$pswd", FILE_APPEND); // put in data 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the form (labels & input) centered, in which case you could add margin to your form:

```
form {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This did it!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`<label>` is not a block by default and text-align works only if the tag has `<div>`'s behavior.

This should be good to start:

```
label {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `label` is an inline element, and is therefore only as big as the text it contains.

The possible is to display your `label` as a block element like this:

```
.data label {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and this solved my problem.

```css
label {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a simple code to your file that is given below:

```html
<style>
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.